# Fairlight (Davinci Resolve 16.2) Upmix chain

Tags: film-sound-design

I am new to sound design. I am a filmmaker. I will be endeavoring to upmix a stereo source to 5.1 manually with the tools available to me in Fairlight within DaVinci Resolve (DR) 16.2

My first thoughts are to do some simple addition and subtraction of the original 2 channels and add various levels of reverb or other effects and patch the results to the Ls and Rs channels...

I think that the placement of a stereo source into a mono channel in Fairlight will simply do an addition. But I am not sure how I would go about doing subtraction of the original 2 channels...

Are there any people familiar with Fairlight in DR 16.2 that would know how to do a subtraction?[image]

Comment: Mark, this is not going to work. It will not provide you with an upmix. You are simply mixing the L/R channels to the centre and then routing a difference signal to both of the the rear channels.